# How to compile and run C++ code using Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, build, cmake

I'm using jenkins to run my tests and do some cr on the code.

From the jenkins localhost, i'm running the following command with my incoming project

```
cmake --build MyProject/cmake-build-debug --target MyProject -- -j 2
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
Error: could not load cache
```

I have all my dependencies installed, and when i run `cmake .`  in MyProject folder i get :

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Main_build/MyProject
```

What could i do to possibly fix this? what is the issue?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding the console output to the jenkins

```
> git checkout -f f7ee4c3501c93aa34ee31a65c0c19de51d16f908
    FATAL: Could not checkout f7ee4c3501c93aa34ee31a65c0c19de51d16f908
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f
    f7ee4c3501c93aa34ee31a65c0c19de51d16f908" returned status code 128:

    stdout: 
    stderr: fatal: cannot create directory at 'MyProject/CMakeFiles/3.13.2': Permission denied

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$900(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2341)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout f7ee4c3501c93aa34ee31a65c0c19de51d16f908
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2365)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1236)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you see the file `CMakeCache.txt` in your project's directories?

Comment: Did you ran `cmake` on your CMakeLists.txt before trying to build your project?

Comment: @bahrep I do see the file CMakeCache.txt. it only appears after i run `cmake .`. and yes @Dan M. i have